# Armature Mirror Problem

Tags: armature, mirror

I'm rigging a model manually because I don't like Rigify. I forgot to enable X-Axis Mirror at the start, and clicking it now does nothing at all for some reason, so I did it the manual way that everyone reading this probably already knows (by default Numpad5, Numpad1, Shift+C, ., Shift+D, S, X, -1). This looks fine in edit mode, but when I go to object or pose mode the hand is twisted the wrong way, the arm IK works strangely, and the pole target (the sphere) is in the wrong place. As well as this, some bones are mispositioned slightly, but this is not a big problem. Anyone able to help?

UPDATE: Interestingly, when I parented the armature to the mesh with automatic weights, the mesh snapped into place exactly around the bones. Picture at the very bottom.

[image: Edit Mode]

(Above) The entire armature as seen in edit mode.

[image: Pose Mode]

(Above) The problems as seen in pose mode.

[image: mhm]

(Above) The mesh snapping into place when parented.

Comment: Did you have the pivot point set to cursor? Did you apply (Ctrl A) rotation and scale of both armature and object before performing mirroring and parenting? If this doesn't solve you should upload your file.

Comment: The file is now completely screwed up; all the bones have twisted the mesh into weird positions even though they weren't applied to it.

Comment: If you remove the armature modifier from the object, the mesh should come back to its original shape.

Answer (score 1):

In Edit Mode with the bone(s) selected that you've moved, go to Armature, then Symmetrize.